# How to append files in another object ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have an array of files for appending them in form data later, but first i need to compress them and append in new array of already compressed files. **I'm stuck with appending files to new array in loop**.

*What i did tried:*

```
const [compressedImages, setCompressedImages] = useState([]);
```

In loop:

```
setCompressedImages(...compressed) //it doesn't seem to work
```

one more try:
(in loop)

```
compressedImages = [...compressed] //doesn't work
```

OR

```
compressedImages.push(compressed) //doesn't work
```

Why spread operator doesn't work in that case ?

**What do I have**

```
<input
       type="file"
       multiple
       onChange={e => selectImages(e)}
  />
```

Function selectImages:

```
const [images , setImages] = useState([]);
const selectImages = e => {
        setImages(e.target.files);
    }
```

Then I need to compress my files and append them all in another array.

```
for (let i = 0; i<images.length; i++){
            let compressed = await imageCompression(images[i], options)
            images = [...compressed]
            //at the end of the loop I must have exactly the same array as 'images' 
            //but with already processed files
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an element to an array state, you should create a new array based on current state and add the new element to it, then set the new array as state:

```js
const [myState, setMyState] = useState([]);
// Add an element to state(long way)
myState.push('element');
setMyState(myState);
// Add an element to state(short way)
setMyState([...myState, 'element']);
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: compressed is not iterable

Comment: Try rechecking your variable names @Grandeamore

Comment: compressedImages setting by using setter setCompressedImages. I guess you meant:
if i have:
 let compressed = await imageCompression(e,options);
setCompressedImages([...compressed])
    instead of suggested:
setCompressedImages([...compressedImages]).
But nevertheless it is not iterable

Comment: Is `compressed` an element that you want to add to `compressedImages`? If so, you can `setCompressedImages([...compressedImages, compressed])` @Grandeamore

Comment: It is working ! Thanks! 
I used state.push in loop and put setter after loop.